# QSizeGrip and Qt::Popup

Tags: c++, qt

When I add a `QSizeGrip` to a widget (like `QWidget` or `QDialog`) and then enable the `Qt::Popup` window flag, the size grip does not work anymore.

Why so?

I would like to create a *resizeable* borderless popup window, like the one used in `QCompleter`. Setting the `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` flag seems to make it borderless but the focus behaviour is quite different..

Answer (score 1):

After reading through the Qt sources, I found two possible solutions, kind of.

Basically, the `QSizeGrip` provides a basic implementation that is perfectly fine and works even when `Qt::Popup` is set or when the window is borderless for other reasons. However, Qt tries to use a platform specific mechanism to offer the size grip.

At least unter Linux/X11 this mechanism seems to fail when the `Qt::Popup` flag is set.

The idea is to bypass using the platform specific mechanism and always use the basic implementation (a.k.a. Qt's fallback). This is achieved by either

- setting the `Qt::BypassWindowManagerHint` flag or
- re-implementing `QWidget::hasHeightForWidth()` to return true (and appropriately provide a neutral `Qt::heightForWidth()`).